# Javascript Random Quote Generator - how to have quote appear as page first loads

Tags: javascript

I am building a random quote generator as my first javascript project. I am getting the quotes to work fine, but I would love to have them displaying as someone first visits the site as well as when the button is clicked.

Here is my code so far:

```
<div id="quoteDisplay">
  <!-- Quotes will display here -->
</div>

  <!-- Center is added for button placement -->
  <button onclick="newQuote()">New Quote</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="ron.js"></script>
```

and the javascript:

```
var quotes = ["quote 1", "quote 2", "quote 3"];

function newQuote() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
}
```

any suggestions on what to add to make a quote display when a user first visits page?

Comment: Take a look at [`Document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).

Comment: @alex: why? The element is already on the page.

Comment: [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Comment: @DavidThomas Matthew said he wanted a random quote to display when the page loads.  You have to use Javascript to randomly generate a quote.  You can either create a new DOM element to hold the string in, or inject the string into an existing DOM element.  The documentation I suggested that he look at was concerning creating elements dynamically.  He could create the `<div id="quoteDisplay"/>` element dynamically if he wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Just call your function on page load:

```
window.addEventListener('load', newQuote, true);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To make a function run as soon as a user loads the page do add this at the end of your script:

```
window.onload = newQuote;
```

or do it with an html body attribute

```
<body onload="newQuote()">
```

Comment: Oh perfect. That was much easier than I was expecting it to be. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just call `newQuote();` in the script after its definition since the dependent HTML has already been processed above the `<script>` tag. No need for adding an `onload` event listener.

```js
var quotes = ["quote 1", "quote 2", "quote 3"];

function newQuote() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
}

newQuote();
```

```html
<div id="quoteDisplay">
  <!-- Quotes will display here -->
</div>
<!-- Center is added for button placement -->

<button onclick="newQuote()">New Quote</button>

<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="ron.js"></script> -->
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach, moving away from the use of obtrusive JavaScript — using inline event-handlers, such as `onclick`, `onblur` — is the following:

```js
// the quotes:
let quotes = ["quote 1", "quote 2", "quote 3", ],

  // the button to which the click event is bound:
  button = document.querySelector('#changeQuote'),

  // a created click-event (any other name could be used
  // but since we're binding a click event-handler it
  // it makes sense to create a named 'click' event:
  clickEvent = new Event('click');

// using EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the newQuote()
// function - note the deliberate lack of parentheses, it's not
// a mistake - as the event-handler for the 'click' event:
button.addEventListener('click', newQuote);

// here we trigger the event using EventTarget.dispatchEvent():
button.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);

function newQuote() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
}
```

```html
<div id="quoteDisplay"></div>
<button id="changeQuote">Change quote</button>
```

References:

- [`Event()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).